# ASP.NET Timer: call JS before tick

Tags: asp.net, timer

I want to call js method before postback after timer tick. How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

User before ajax call event, you have to register that first
Registering event

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.instance.add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandler)
```

Event handler

```
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
    alert("Before ajax call");
}
```